# MySQL Permission for performing backup

Tags: mysql, percona, mysql-backup

What are the minimum required permissions for a mysql user to perform a backup using mysqldump/xtrabackup? I do not want permissions to power like root, but just enough to perform a backup. This is becasue innobackupex requires you to add the password on command line, which is not too secure. So i would like to create another user with not so much privileges to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On MySQL this would be these permissions as far as I know:

```
GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES, RELOAD, SHOW VIEW ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Note that it may vary if you use views, functions, procedures etc

Comment: This command works for mysqldump, but not for innobackupex. I also added 'user'@'127.0.0.1' to make it run for innobackupex, but after running well, the command ended up with this error: 170513 10:58:35 Executing LOCK TABLES FOR BACKUP...
Error: failed to execute query LOCK TABLES FOR BACKUP: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: @TheGeorgia I've edited the statement, it should grant reload privileges now

Comment: All the privileges you need for xtrabackup include SELECT, LOCK TABLES, RELOAD, TRIGGER, SUPER, REPLICATION CLIENT, SHOW VIEW ON . Thanks @FMashiro for giving me a direction.